# Can we use present perfect for future event?

Tags: sentence-construction

I heard someone like "they have been married in two years so we should be married in two years.
'Have been married' for future event? I don't get it.

Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence does not quite parse correctly, so forgive me if I have misunderstood.

I *think* this is essentially part of an argument, where the speaker is using the example of two people who *did* get married within two years of meeting to justify why the *speaker* should also expect to be married within two years of meeting their own partner.

However, **have been** and **in** don't go together properly.  As I see it (listed from more-formal to more-casual), it should be:

- They **were** married **within** two years, so we should **be** married **within** two years
- They **got** married **within** two years, so we should **get** married **within** two years
- They **got** married **in** two years, so we should **get** married **in** two years

When casually speaking, **within** and **in** are interchangeable, as are **were** and **got** (although this is *not* necessarily true of all possible uses of **within**/**in** or **were**/**got**).

**Have been** would be used to describe the length of the marriage, not the time it took to get married, and would be coupled with **for**, not **in**.

- They *have been* married *for* two years.

However, since you would not *reasonably*<sup>[1]</sup> expect to compare the length of a marriage to the length of time waiting *before* marriage, I would not expect to see this conjoined to the second part of the original sentence:

- <del>"They *have been* married *for* two years, so we should *be* married *within* two years.</del>

(Although it is a valid *construction*, it would be harder to understand using context alone.)

You *might*, however, be able to justify comparing two marriage lengths:

- They *have been* married *for* two years, so we should *be* married *for* two years.

---

[1] Note that I am not commenting on the validity of the *arguments*, here.  There are many cases where [logical fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies) are deliberately employed to win arguments.

Comment: Yes it was a part of an argument. Is this American way of speaking?

Comment: @Rocky : I don't *think* so.  It may indeed be a dialect (or educational) issue, but I don't think it is specifically *American English* (noting that I am British).  It could just be that, in the heat of the argument, proper grammar *wasn't* the speaker's primary focus.

Comment: What? I mean like you a native english speaker can also make grammatical mistake? I thought that native speakers speak perfectly. Do they make mistakes?

Comment: Just in case my sarcasm radar isn't working today, then yes, of course we do -- all the time.  Most of us just say the bare minimum that we need to, to be understood, and if we're understood, that's good enough.

Comment: That's new to me.

Comment: @jimbobmcgee it's no different in American English. But it's a pretty specific grammatical structure.